# Cannot link custom domain to azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There are certain variations to this question but none answered mine.

I have a custom domain aaaskills.mydomain.com pointing to azure website. 
This was done by setting CNAME to aaaskills.mydomain.com -> azure website. This is all working fine. Good.

But I want to change the subdomain to skills.mydomain.com, so i updated the existing CNAME to skills.mydomain.com -> azure website. All good.

Now, in my Azure portal i'm trying to add a new hostname for new domain but the azure doesn't recognize the CNAME updated.

Now aaaskills.mydomain.com doesn't work and skills.mydomain.com is bringing up 404 not found and it is suggesting me to update custom domain in azure website.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain ownership on azure website was resolved after awverify'ing the sub domain. I added CNAME with records like below to awverify.

CNAME('awverify.subdomain.domain.com','azure website url')